# Sort an array of objects fetched from database

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, sorting

I am using codeigniter. In one of my models i have defined a function which retrieves data from database from two tables using UNION. I want my retrieved array of objects to be sorted on 'date_submitted' property. I tried to use the following code but it is not showing the desired result.

Here is my code

```
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("artwork");
    $this->db->get(); 
    $query1 = $this->db->last_query();

    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("blog");
    $this->db->get(); 
    $query2 =  $this->db->last_query();

    $results = $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2);

    function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a->date_submitted == $b->date_submitted) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a->date_submitted < $b->date_submitted) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    usort($results->result(), "cmp");
    var_dump($results->result());
```

It gives the following output

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[31]
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'title' => string 'My Painting2' (length=12)
      public 'category' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'date_submitted' => string '2014-09-26 23:00:09' (length=19)

  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[32]
      public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'title' => string 'Second artwork' (length=14)
      public 'category' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'date_submitted' => string '2014-09-27 01:09:03' (length=19)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[33]
      public 'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'title' => string 'Test Title' (length=10)
      public 'category' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'date_submitted' => string '2014-10-12 01:19:34' (length=19)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[34]
      public 'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'title' => string 'Test Title' (length=10)
      public 'category' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'date_submitted' => string '2014-10-12 02:54:57' (length=19)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[35]
      public 'id' => string '8' (length=1)
      public 'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'title' => string 'test' (length=4)
      public 'category' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'date_submitted' => string '2014-11-13 16:49:06' (length=19)
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)[36]
      public 'id' => string '9' (length=1)
      public 'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'title' => string 'Hello World' (length=11)
      public 'category' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'date_submitted' => string '2014-12-06 22:15:46' (length=19)
  6 => 
    object(stdClass)[37]
      public 'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      public 'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'title' => string 'My first blog' (length=13)
      public 'category' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'date_submitted' => string '2014-10-12 21:26:13' (length=19)
```

The first 6 rows are from first table and the last row is from 2nd table.

Comment: Why don't you order it in your SQL query? '$results = $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2 ." ORDER BY `date_dubmitted`");'

Comment: Mark my answer as the actual answer so people stop commenting or searching any further if they are stuck on a problem like this too. :)

Comment: But i still don't understand why my logic did not give the required result?

Comment: The difference between date formats in php are a big issue. Read some more about that and you might find your answer there. Its located in the date_diff function from PHP

Comment: Wait. That's from another question. The union is the one that messes up for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people who don't read comments. All that has to be done is adding the 'Order By' attribute from SQL to your query like so;

```
$results = $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2 ." ORDER BY date_dubmitted")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert the date time string to unix timestamp and compare:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        $firstTimeStamp = strtotime( $a->date_submitted );
        $secondTimeStamp = strtotime( $b->date_submitted );

        if ( $firstTimeStamp == $secondTimeStamp ) {
            return 0;
        }

        return ( $firstTimeStamp < $secondTimeStamp ) ? -1 : 1;
    }
```